# What is the chance of getting a number less than $0.01$ when using Math.random()?

Tags: probability

When using Math.random() in JavaScript in Google Firebase Functions I get $17$ decimal places like this:

$$0.35361536181287034$$

I wanted to see what the chance is of getting any number where the first two decimals are $0$ like this:

$$0.00361536181287034$$

Can I say with some accuracy that it is about $1$ in $100$ because there are $100$ possibilities for the first $2$ decimals $(00-99)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2015, every major JavaScript engine<sup>[1](https://v8.dev/blog/math-random)</sup> implements `Math.random()` using the `xorshift128+` algorithm, which passes the [TestU01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TestU01) suite. So the accuracy is *pretty* good. The true probability that `Math.random() < 0.01` is likely somewhere within a few Float64 epsilons of $0.01$, let's say $\pm10^{-17}$. Assuming your application is going to call this function less than $10^{36}$ times during its lifetime, its random noise is going to swamp such a tiny bias anyway.

So, short answer: yes!

Answer (score 4):

In a perfect world with perfect random number generators, $P(X<c)=c$ for every $0\le c\le 1$.